# SQL Ordering by a substring with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have data that looks like this:

```
[Model Number]
[Model Number]*1
[Model Number]*4
[Model Number]*10
[Model Number]*13
```

And when I select them I would liek to order them by the number after the " * ", I have it almost working but I dont know how to deal with the case where I dont have a " * ". Here is the last part of my query:

```
ORDER BY 
CAST(SUBSTRING(COL_NAME, CHARINDEX('*', COL_NAME) + 1, LEN(COL_NAME)) AS INT) DESC
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of solutions that should get you what you're after:

```
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(int,RIGHT(COL_NAME, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('*',REVERSE(COL_NAME)),0) -1)) DESC;

ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(int, STUFF(COL_NAME, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('*', COL_NAME),0),'')) DESC;
```

The `NULLIF` resolves the issue if there is no `'*'`, as `CHARINDEX` will return `0`. Then you don't end up passing an invalid (negative) value to the `RIGHT` function, as `NULL - 1 = NULL`.

My personal preference would be using `STUFF`, as `REVERSE` is quite an expensive function.

Comment: Is there an alternative to TRY_CONVERT, I believe my sql sever version is too old?

Comment: @ChristopheSirois `TRY_CONVERT` is available from SQL Server 2012, so I would *hope* you have access to it; SQL Server 2008 is almost completely out of support now. If not, you'll have to use `CONVERT` and hope you don't have a value like `'[Model Number]*1A'`.

Comment: Thanks! Convert worked, If I make sure only INT values are after the " * " I should not have any problems? It is not my server unfortunatly and it is still on SQL server 2008

Comment: If there are only numerical characters after the `'*'` then you won't have any issues, no.My solution does assume that you want the order of your rows to be `1,2,3,4...10,11,12...20,21, etc` (numerical ordering) rather than `1,10,11,...2,20,21,22, etc` (character ordering). If you want the latter ordering then get rid of the `CONVERT`.altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, try this

```
declare @t table (col_name varchar(128));
insert into @t (col_name)
values
( '[Model Number]')
, ('[Model Number]*1')
, ('[Model Number]*4')
, ('[Model Number]*10')
, ('[Model Number]*13');

select *
from @t
order by case charindex('*', col_name) when 0 then 0 else cast(substring(col_name, charindex('*', col_name)+1, 10) as int) end desc
```

[image]

Comment: The case statement has int data type precedence, so doesn't need to be cast.